# Django templates: Show regroup groups in arbitrary order?

Tags: django

If we use the example from the django docs,

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]
```

**How can I show the results grouped by an arbitrary sub/superset of countries in an arbitrary order?**

**Can it be done in the template better than my current solution (see below), or is it better to manipulate the dataset in the view?**

e.g. say I want to show the groups in this order: ('Japan', 'USA', 'Australia')

`{% for country in country_list|dictsort:"grouper" %}` doesn't work because:

- The desired order is not alphabetical
- I want to show "Australia" even if `cities` doesn't include any Australian cities
- I don't want to show India

The reason for this that in my use case (not actually about countries and cities), I need to put my data into a table, grouped by ('Japan', 'USA', 'Australia') as columns, and grouped by some other field as rows.

Currently doing it like this:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
    <li>Japan
    {% for country in country_list %}
        {% if country.grouper == "Japan" %}
            <ul>
            {% for city in country.list %}
                <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
    <li>USA
    {% for country in country_list %}
        {% if country.grouper == "USA" %}
            <ul>
            {% for city in country.list %}
                <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
    <li>Australia
    {% for country in country_list %}
        {% if country.grouper == "Australia" %}
            <ul>
            {% for city in country.list %}
                <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Thanks in advance!**